# How would you go on to manipulate return values of functions in C, given the number of times the function was called upon on?

Tags: c, function

"Write a function which will return 100 the first time it's called, the second time it's called it should return 99, third 98, etc. - once the number reaches zero, function should always return 0".

I'm absolutely lost here, because it could easily be done via

```
int func()

{

int x = 100;

if ( x == 0 )
return 0;
else
return x;

--x;

}
```

but that obviously doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: `static int x = 100;` and `return x--;`

Comment: Or just use a global variable

Comment: A `static` is probably the better choice since a global could be altered from anywhere else in the code and therefore cause the function to produce an incorrect result.

Comment: FIx the indentation of your code.

Comment: Kenobai, you have two answers, won't you say anything? :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(void) {
        static int x = 100;
        return x ? x-- : 0;
}

int main(void) {
        int i;
        // Until 105 to see that it always returns 0 after 100 calls
        for(i = 0; i < 105; ++i)
                printf("%d\n", func());
        return 0;
}
```

The `static` keyword says that `x`'s value should not be vanished, after the termination of `func()`, so that when `func()` is called for the second time, `x` will have the same value as on the termination of `func()`.

Note that `static int x = 100;` will be executed once, that means that `x` won't receive value 100 on second call of `func()`.

---

If confuses `return x ? x-- : 0;` you, it's just equivalent to this:

```
if(x == 0)
    return 0;
return x--;
```

Comment: This doesn't fulfill the requirement of returning zero after `x` has reached zero.

Comment: Updated @EOF, is it better now? :)

Comment: Why too verbose. `return x ? x-- : 0;` ;-)

Comment: `return x ? x-- : x;`

Comment: I like @EOF's better, because it shows the purpose of the else statement. Thanks both!

Comment: Hmm, something like `static int x = 101; return x-=!!x;` might actually perform better...

Comment: @EOF yeah if we would like to sent the beginner to the hospital! :)) Yeah multithreading is also something that we should not cover here.. :)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Exactly why this would be faster: It doesn't need to make the store to `x` conditional.

Answer (score -1):

### Define your function like this:

```
    int func() 
     {
        static int x = 100;
        if (x==0)
            return 0;
        else
            return x--;
     }
```

---

The magic happens because of the static qualifier attached to integer variable.
static variables are part of the data section of your program even though it is declared and defined inside a function. The data section gets initialized once at the time the program is loaded. So when you call this function, the static int x will be initialized 100 only once.

Comment: "Write a function which will return 100 the first time" --> this returns 99 the first time.

Comment: Jayaprakash Nevara,  The original posted function was  `int func()  { static int x = 100; if (x==0) return 0; else return --x; }` and that does return 99 the first time called, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615936/how-would-you-go-on-to-manipulate-return-values-of-functions-in-c-given-the-num/37618609?noredirect=1#comment62723185_37618609).  It was 7 years ago this answer was down voted - likely for that reason.  Not my down-vote.  The code was modified 4 year later with a correction.

Comment: Jayaprakash Nevara, It would be good to comment with  `@user_name` to notify a commenter (me in this case) of the code correction 3 years ago.